# Full text search support in Java and PHP application

Tags: java, php, elasticsearch, full-text-search, laravel-scout

My application is build on **Java(version 1.8) with framework hibernate 5.2** and **PHP(version 7.0) with framework laravel 5.2**.
I want to apply full text search like [Elastic Search](https://www.elastic.co/), [TNTSearch](https://github.com/teamtnt/laravel-scout-tntsearch-driver), [Laravel Scout](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scout).

**Problem :**

In database tables insert and update from both application(Java and PHP) very frequently. But as per my information any search algorithm work when CRUD operation done by single application(either Java or PHP) as I found this problem while try to apply full text search.

Am I right or Not?

Help me what should I do in this case. I appreciate all response.

Thanks Ahead.

Answer (score 0):

You should forward your crud operations to your search engine so that the data there is the same as the data in your DB.

Then searching is a completely different operation, which won't involve your DB, but only the search engine you're using.

Comment: Jerska thanks for your answer but your answer force me to to use CRUD operatons either Java or PHP. but I can't do it now. Is any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a layer between your database and your application. Let's call it the CRUD layer. Now, the CRUD layer will be a REST API, written either in PHP or Java, it's your choise. The CRUD layer will have the responsibility of writing to the database and updating the full text search index accordingly.

After you have this layer, all of your crud operations will hit this layer first no matter if the requests come from Java or PHP or any other language

Comment: Nenad, how can I do this in existing project where more than 300 API exists. Can you suggest?

Comment: Actually, I am not able to understand How can create CRUD Layer in existing project. Is it possible to syncing by java and php in same place in elastic search?